# construct tree from ancestor matrix

Tags: algorithm, tree

You are given a matrix M[n, n] for a tree with n nodes. In the given matrix M, M[i, j] is true iff node j is an ancestor of node i. Construct the tree from the given matrix.

For example, you are given below matrix.

```
   1  2  3  4
1  0  1  1  0

2  0  0  1  0

3  0  0  0  0

4  0  1  1  0
```

You need to construct the below tree. In the constructed tree ancestor relationship should be correct. A node can come on left or right of its parent as you cannot determine this information from the ancestor matrix

```
Node numbers used in matrix are in bracket
                        5(3)
                         |     
                         |   
                        10(2)
                        /    \
                       /      \
                   12(1)    13(4)
```

Comment: While Stack Overflow may help you as you work on your homework, it's not a place where you can just paste you homework questions and get answers to them.  What Have You Tried?  http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: I was just thinking to do that way by considering the level order traversal ... the one with all zeros will be root and so on ...  but looking for a more efficient solution ....

Comment: This has been explained nicely [here](http://rawkam.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/build-tree-from-ancestor-matrix/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are good algorithms for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting which should apply in this case